# Order of async function execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, backend

I have a problem with handling the response of my async function in socket.io.

This is the main function, that I am dealing with.

```
return self.loadFiles()
            .then(resolve) // 'Acknowledgment'
            .catch(reject)
            .then(_ => {
                socket.emit('RESPONSE', 'socketEmitResponse')
            })
```

loadFiles and serveFiles are both asyncFunctions.
The Promise will eventually resolve here:

```
postAuthenticate : (socket) => {
    socket.on('syncEvent', function(data, callback) {

        return sync.syncThis(data)
        .catch(errorHandler)
        .then(callback)

    })
}
```

Currently the response looks something like this:

```
> socketEmitResponse
> Acknowledgement
```

What I want is that the callback will execute first and then the emitResponse. How can I achieve that?

Comment: So `sync.syncThis(data)` is returning `self.loadFiles ....` is this right ?

Comment: Correct! Forgot to mention that

Comment: Then simply calling `callback('socketCallback');` before `return sync.syncThis(data)` will do the job, isn't it ?

Comment: I edited my post. What I need is the resolved value from syncThis

Comment: Can you then just move `.then(_ => {
                socket.emit('RESPONSE', 'socketEmitResponse')
            })` after `.then(callback)`